# Why are gauge symmetries continuous?

Tags: gauge-symmetry

All gauge theories that are considered in literature are continuous $SU(N)$ symmetric. My question is why are always continuous groups considered for gauge symmetries? Why don't we consider discrete groups like $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Comment: Noether's theorem applies to continuous symmetries

Comment: I do not understand the question - by definition, a gauge symmetry is a local symmetry given by smooth maps into a Lie group. What would a gauge symmetry be if not that? You can't just say "local discrete symmetry", because the idea of a smooth map $\text{spacetime}\to\text{group}$ giving the local transformation isn't well-defined, since non-Lie groups do not carry a smooth structure at all (they aren't manifolds).

Comment: I am no expert, but I believe discrete gauge theories are useful for modelling topological excitations in two spatial dimensions. Presumably "gauge symmetry" here means a symmetry of degrees of freedom which are inaccessible by local measurements (e.g. you have to do some kind of Aharonov-Bohm interferometry to measure the fluxes and charges). [These lecture notes](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9511201) cover the topic.

Comment: @MarkMitchison: The paper is very interesting, but it "cheats" - they don't have a discrete gauge group, they have a continuous gauge group which is spontaneously broken into a discrete group, so the *space of states* only carries a discrete symmetry, while the underlying Lagrangian - the level on which a gauge symmetry is formulated - still has a continuous symmetry. The discrete group doesn't actually gain the status of being a gauge group itself.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I see what you mean. Nevertheless, the use of the term "gauge symmetry" to describe a locally inaccessible property of the quantum states is perfectly common within that field. I don't really understand why there are close votes on this question, to me it is perfectly clear what is being asked, and there is obviously a good answer lurking somewhere within those lecture notes or the other published literature.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I guess I am just saying that you are using one definition that is not universal outside of field theory and high-energy physics. In trying to understand certain condensed matter systems, you might not start from the YM Lagrangian. Instead, you could write down an effective Hamiltonian describing the long-range physics, e.g. the toric code. You then find that this Hamiltonian is invariant under discrete transformations between groups of states that are experimentally indistinguishable *in principle* within the model universe. I think this is a decent definition of gauge symmetry

Comment: (However it would always be true that in the real world there exist measurements at high enough energy that could distinguish the "internal states", unlike in YM theory as I understand it.)

Comment: @MarkMitchison: That makes sense, and I retract my close vote. I would appreciate this definition of gauge symmetry being included into the question, since I would *never* have interpreted that into the question.